# Vue.js Cannot read property 'length' of null

Tags: javascript, vue.js

If I do this:

```
<div class="panel panel-default" v-if="socialiteLogins !== null">
```

The panel doesn't hide. If I check `socialiteLogins === null` alone, or with ==, they both return that the object isn't null. It's definitely null though. If I dump it on the page, I get [] as the result. It's an empty json object. So if I try this:

```
<div class="panel panel-default" v-if="socialiteLogins.length !== 0">
```

The panel still doesn't hide and I get this error:

> Cannot read property 'length' of null

But If I do this:

```
<div class="panel panel-default" v-if="socialiteLogins !== null && socialiteLogins.length !== 0">
```

It hides the panel perfectly with no warnings on initial load but when I update the socialiteLogins variable later I get the length warning if it ever returns an empty json object again. Any idea why?

Edit:

Adding to it... if I do this:

```
<div class="panel panel-default" v-show="socialiteLogins">
```

It shows on initial load even though there are none, but if I remove them after the page loads it properly hides the panel. So the only issue appears to be the initial loading where it's not properly detecting that there are no records.

Comment: Perhaps there is a typo in your question; the first example you say doesn't work, but the final example is exactly the same and you say that works.

Comment: @RyanZim There was, thanks, plus I did more testing and it still doesn't work so I updated the question.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

@RyanZim's answer helped. Here's the solution in case anyone else comes here by search in the future.

The issue arises from the initial state of the data. For instance, I had this:

```
data: function() {
    return {
        socialiteLogins: null
    }
},
```

Which works for !== null but not for checking .length. Later when it returns an empty object, .legnth will work but not null.

So the solution is keeping it the proper type the entire time so that I can run a consistent check:

```
data: function() {
    return {
        socialiteLogins: []
    }
},
```

Comment: Not sure if it's a typo or not; the intent of your code would be clearer if you set the initial value to an empty array (`[]`), instead of an empty object.

Comment: Thanks! Saved me a lot of time

Answer (score 15):

I am no expert on Vue.js, but the following applies to JS in general.

---

If `socialiteLogins` is `null` or `undefined`, you can't read the `length` property of it. That only can be read if `socialiteLogins` is an array, object, or function. That is why you get the message:

> Cannot read property 'length' of null

If `socialiteLogins` is `undefined` or an empty array, `socialiteLogins !== null`. However, `socialiteLogins == null` (Note that this is using loose comparison).

If `socialiteLogins` is an empty array, it is still truthy. `v-show` will regard it as `true`.

The combination of these facts is making your code not work.

---

In your case, I think this will work:

```
 <div class="panel panel-default" v-show="socialiteLogins && socialiteLogins.length">
```

**How it works:**

The JS `&&` operator evaluates the first statement; if it is truthy, it returns the value of the second statement. If the first statement is falsy, it returns its value.

`v-show` coerces the result of the expression to a boolean.

If `socialiteLogins` is `undefined` or `null`, it returns that value, which is coerced to `false`.

If `socialiteLogins` is an empty array, `socialiteLogins` is truthy, so `&&` returns the second statement; `socialiteLogins.length` will be `0`. That will be coerced to `false` as well.

If `socialiteLogins` is an array with contents, `socialiteLogins` will be truthy, and `socialiteLogins.length` will be a non-zero number, which will be coerced to `true`.

Comment: IMO, [Citizen answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40754293/12085129) below is better. For me it's better to define an initial state rather than adding checks everywhere. What if you must check this condition 10 times in your template ? Defining a state like `socialiteLogins: []` in `data` of your view component is for me a better solution.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the tip for you.

```
<div class="panel panel-default" v-if="Object.keys(socialiteLogins).length > 0">
```

and here we go that's all.

mark as answered.