# Cannot read property 'length' of undefined"

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am getting the error below. The weird part is that I'm positive the data is there because in my vue add on I can see that it successfully grabs the information from the vuex store. My initial guess is that somehow the data is not yet grabbed from the store, at the point that it creates the template?

```
Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined"
```

**The data:** 'spaces' is grabbed from the store.

```
    export default {
        name: "myspaces",
        data() {
            return {
                filterMaxLength: 3,
                selectedSpace: 0,
                selectedRoom: 0
            }
        },
        created() {
            // Default selected space (first in json)
            this.selectedSpace = this.spaces[0].id;

            // Default selected room (first in json)
            this.selectedRoom = this.spaces[0].rooms[0].id;
        },
        computed: {
            // Get 'spaces' from store.
            ...mapState([
                'spaces'
            ])
    }
```

**Template:**

```
<template>
      <div>  
         <v-flex v-if="spaces.length < filterMaxLength">
              <v-btn v-for="space in spaces">
                 <h4> {{space.name}} </h4>
              </v-btn>
         </v-flex>
     </div>
<template>
```

**The store:**

```
    import Vuex from 'vuex'

Vue.use(Vuex);

export default new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        spaces:[
            {
                id:1,
                name:'House in Amsterdam',
                rooms:[
                    {
                        id:1,
                        name:'Bedroom Otto',
                    },
                    {
                        id:2,
                        name:'Bedroom Mischa'
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                id:2,
                name:'Office in Amsterdam',
                rooms:[
                    {
                        id:1,
                        name:'Office 1',
                    },
                    {
                        id:2,
                        name:'Office 2'
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]} });
```

**The vue chrome add on says this information is in the component:**

[image]

Comment: Show us your store code

Comment: Does your store get spaces from an external source? Probably you're just missing the data.

Comment: I added the store, however like I was trying to show with the vue addon it does detect the data on the component page.

Comment: `spaces` is undefined until your store returns the data, so you can't read its `length` at that point. You just need to tweak the template such that it can cope with undefined data while it's waiting for the store; `v-if="spaces && spaces.length < filterMaxLength"` might be sufficient.

Comment: @DanielBeck Hi Daniel, thanks for the reply, turns out.... that while copy and pasting code from an older file to my new project. I forgot to add certain props like `room.images` etc. Hence those were undefined! So problem solved!

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/61656999/5187169](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61656999/5187169) You check my answer in this section thanks.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Always before check length, be sure your property its set then check length

```
<v-flex v-if="spaces && spaces.length < filterMaxLength">
```

**Update ECMAScript 2020**

You can use [Optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) for this purpose too

```
<v-flex v-if="spaces?.length < filterMaxLength">
```

Answer (score 6):

You should use `Object.keys(spaces).length`, such as:

```
<template>
      <div>  
         <v-flex v-if="typeof spaces !== 'undefined' && typeof spaces === 'object' && Object.keys(spaces).length < filterMaxLength">
              <v-btn v-for="space in spaces">
                 <h4> {{space.name}} </h4>
              </v-btn>
         </v-flex>
     </div>
<template>
```

Answer (score 0):

just to be sure you have following in your vue

```
import { mapState } from "vuex";
```

---

Else, you can use getters also, eg. :

**In your vue file**

```
v-if="this.getSpaces.length !== 0"
```

**In computed fonctions of your vue file**

```
getSpaces() {

  return this.$store.getters.getSpaces;

}
```

**In your store**

```
getters: {
    getSpaces: state => {
      return state.spaces;
    }
},
```

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem, I imported a sass style sheet with `functions(@mixins)` and a sass style sheet with variables into one sass style sheet.

I imported them as

```
(
@import url('./_variables.scss');
@import url('./_func.scss');
)
```

so i just took out the `url()` for both import statements and that error went away.